# Is it possible to establish two connection to the same SQLite database simultaneously?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I have a executable jar file that inserts data into a SQLite database. This insertion, however, is taking so longer than I expected. I thought I might be able to create another copy of this jar file to HELP the first one.

The reason why this process is so slow is not because my CPU is working 100%, but because the process itself is time-consuming.

By the way, during this process no row will be deleted. it's just INSERT and UPDATE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update to Sqlite database from multiple connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325683/update-to-sqlite-database-from-multiple-connections)

Comment: I think I found the answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325683/update-to-sqlite-database-from-multiple-connections