# Parallel query of SQLite database in R

Tags: foreach, parallel-processing, domc, rsqlite

I have a large database (~100Gb) from which I need to pull every entry, 
perform some comparisons on it, and then store the results of those comparisons. I have attempted to run parallel queries within a single R sessions without any success. I can just run multiple R sessions all at once but I am looking for a better approach. Here is what I attempted:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)
library(foreach)
library(doMC)



#---------
# SETUP
#---------


#connect to db
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="genes_drug_combos.sqlite")


#---------
# QUERY
#---------
# 856086 combos = 1309 * 109 * 6

registerDoMC(8)

#I would run 6 seperate R sessions (one for each i)
res_list <- foreach(i=1:6) %dopar% {

  a <- i*109-108
  b <- i*109

  pb  <- txtProgressBar(min=a, max=b, style=3)
  res <- list()

  for (j in a:b) {

    #get preds for drug combos
    statement   <- paste("SELECT * from combo_tstats WHERE rowid BETWEEN", (j*1309)-1308, "AND", j*1309)
    combo_preds <- dbGetQuery(db, statement)

    #here I do some stuff to the result returned from the query
    combo_names <- combo_preds$drug_combo
    combo_preds <- as.data.frame(t(combo_preds[,-1]))

    colnames(combo_preds)  <- combo_names

    #get top drug combos
    top_combos <- get_top_drugs(query_genes, drug_info=combo_preds, es=T)

    #update progress and store result
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, j)
    res[[ length(res)+1 ]] <- top_combos
  }
  #bind results together
  res <- rbindlist(res)
}
```

I dont get any errors but only one core spins up. In contrast, if I run multiple R sessions, all my cores go at it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using mac or windows? and do you have Emacs and ESS installed?

Comment: Maybe this article may help https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/211789298-Multiple-R-Sessions-in-RStudio-Server-Pro

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and R studio.

Comment: You need to create one connection per parallel instance, not one connection that's shared across all cores

Comment: That was it - thank you! In general, do any required objects/connections need to be created for each parallel instance?

Answer (score 5):

Some things I have learned while accessing concurrently with `RSQLite` the same file SQLite database:

#### 1. Make sure each worker has its own DB connection.

```
  parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, {
    db.conn <- RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "./export/models.sqlite");
    RSQLite::dbClearResult(RSQLite::dbSendQuery(db.conn, "PRAGMA busy_timeout=5000;"));
  })
```

#### 2. Use `PRAGMA busy_timeout=5000;`

By default this is set to 0, and chances are that you will end up with a "*database is locked*" error each time your worker tries to write to the DB while it is locked. Previous code sets this `PRAGMA` in each worker connection. Note that `SELECT` operations are never locked, only `INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE`.

#### 3. Use `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;`

This only has to be set once and stays on by default forever. It will add two (more or less permanent) files to the DB. It will [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10387821/1548942) concurrent read/write performance. Read more [here](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

With the above settings I have not experienced [this](https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/issues/56) issue.

Comment: I still get `database is locked` errors. Oddly they sometimes happen when the process has been running for less than the `busy_timeout` (I've tried values between 5s and 2min). Any ideas? I guess switching to postgresql would get rid of these problems.

Comment: No need to switch. SQLite is surprisingly fast and easy to use. Check your commits. I have 8 processes running 100% constantly accessing the DB on NTFS partition. If, for example, I start building an index from within the console, I see all 8 processes halt, waiting for the DB to become available again, which happens immediately after index is built. What causes immediate dropouts (i.e. locks) is for example when you run `VACUUM` from within the console.

Comment: I'm using `dbWriteTable`, maybe that's giving trouble. I've been looking for a way to find a log of the database's commits, and can't find anything. Any advice?

Comment: Maybe yes. I always use plain SQL: `dbSendQuery` and `dbGetQuery`.

Comment: @Galadude when you switched to `dbSendQuery` did it fix your problem? I'm also getting `database is locked` errors when used `dbWriteTable`

Comment: dbSendQuery is for SELECT statements, and i need to insert rows.

Comment: No, it is not only for SELECT statements. You can use UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statements too and bind variables through the `param` argument.