# flask sqlalchemy OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask rest API. there is a function which repeats every minute and updates the database(sqlite3). It works for a while but after some time API gets unresponsive and won't respond to requests. I think this function makes the API unresponsive. I can see the error mentioned in the question title. Am I doing anything wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import threading
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
.
.
.
def UpdateStatus():
threading.Timer(60, UpdateStatus).start() 
messages = Message.query.filter((Message.status != 'Seen')).all()
for msg in messages:
    try:
        messageid= msg.messageid
        wamessageid= msg.wamessageid
        timestamp= datetime.now()
        result= driver.get_message_status(wamessageid)
        if result==1:
            status='Sent'
            api_response= 'OK: Message sent'
        elif result==2:
            status= 'Delivered'
            api_response= 'OK: Message Delivered'
        elif result==3:
            status= 'Seen'
            api_response= 'OK: Message Seen'
        message = Message.query.filter_by(messageid = messageid).first()
        if message.status!= status:
            message.status= status
            message.apiresponse= api_response
            if status== 'Delivered':
                message.timestamp_delivered= timestamp
            if status== 'Seen':
                if message.timestamp_delivered is None:
                    message.timestamp_delivered= timestamp
                message.timestamp_seen= timestamp
            db.session.commit()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        continue
```

Comment: what's the path of the db?

Comment: there is no problem with the path. I'm sure about that. because this function works for a while. but after some time I get this error. Anyway updated the code.

Comment: when this error first occurs, will some requests still get through? Or you get this error only once and afterwards it's completely stuck? Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: After I see this error no request goes through and it completely gets stuck.

Comment: Are you sure the db is still readable and writeable after it gets stuck? Because it sounds like the database file is dissapearing

Comment: Almost sure about that. Db file is there and I have no other function to interfere with the database.

Comment: Are you using threading in your app?

Comment: @Fian yes. I do

Comment: Then error may be caused by the db-file locking by one thread during writing (commiting) and simultaneous (concurrent) read/write attempt from the another thread. [See here for more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325683/can-i-read-and-write-to-a-sqlite-database-concurrently-from-multiple-connections)

Comment: may you please guide me how to enable WAL mode in sqlalchemy?

Comment: I've never used it.