# SQLite 3 cannot read edits of database

Tags: database, sqlite, go, rdbms

I am writing a very simple Go app that uses sqlite 3 and during testing I noticed that when I insert a new row into the database with i.e. SQLPro, while the app is running, this app won't notice the new data.

For testing purposes I tried running sqlite3 via command line and adding the data via SQLPro, and still, the select could not show the data that was added to the database after opening it.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you remember to commit?

Comment: Yes, the save is done and if I relaunch my app, it reads it correctly. (Closing the db connection and reopening it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23350768/4466350