# sqflite database concurrently in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, concurrency, sqflite

[SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23350768/13492963) does support "shared-cache" that allows for multiple writes concurrently.

How can I enable concurrency in flutter app to write to sqflite ?