# SQLite: Database Is locked C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, object, exception

EDIT! Here's the video of the error https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mJ3o3ykQrw

Made a method called AddAttendance in my database handler class. I can access it from other class since it's static. Here's the code:

```
 public static void AddAttendance(string ID, string DateTime, string Action, string Session)
        {
            SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = " + database + "; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;");
            try
            {
                sqlite_conn.Open();
                SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AttendanceLog (UserID, DateTime, Action, Session) VALUES (" +
                    "'" + ID + "', '" + DateTime + "', '" + Action + "', '" + Session + "');";
                sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                sqlite_conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            sqlite_conn.Close();
        }
```

This code is only being accessed by this Dialog Form I made bound to a button:

```
 private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBoxID.Text.Length == 0 || textBoxTimeDate.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ID or Time and Date cannot be empty!", "Missing field", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            if (buttonAccept.Text.Equals("Accept"))
            {
                buttonAccept.Text = "Confirm!";
                return;
            }
            DatabaseHandles.AddAttendance(textBoxID.Text, textBoxTimeDate.Text, comboBoxAction.Text, comboBoxSession.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Record added!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
```

If im accessing it from my Form Kiosk mode, it's working just fine, but if I'm accessing it from anywhere else, it reports Database is locked.

What's weird is, when i accessed it first to my Kiosk mode beforehand then to other place, it works just fine.

I dont know what am i missing. Here the same code i use on calling the form:

```
 AttendanceInsert ai = new AttendanceInsert();
                ai.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I'll go ahead and guess there's someplace that leaves a database connection hanging. You should probably use an `using` block to manage the lifetime of the database connection rather than manually `Close`ing it.

Comment: @AKX that's actually weird cause as i say, i have database handler class, and everything there is getting closed. I can access the database from wherever i want without getting this error. Just this specific class does it. Another thing is, i can access the same function from different class just fine.

Comment: You still should use `using`, it'll make things easier for you.

Comment: Side note: **Always use parameterized sql and avoid string concatenation** to add values to sql statements. This mitigates SQL Injection vulnerabilities and ensures values are passed to the statement correctly. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204), and [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325683/can-i-read-and-write-to-a-sqlite-database-concurrently-from-multiple-connections

Comment: read what you put. Unfortunately this is the only thread or class that does writing to the database from the whole program. And what's funny, this is even static, so it's not under influence of any instance either. But then if i accessed it via Kiosk mode form i made, it can write very easily @Otgonbold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was the reader, although I closed all the connection with the `using` parameter, i forgot to close all the readers i used, I should be utilizing `using` here too, but you get the idea. Database is locked with the readers unclosed

```
 public static void LoadScannedUser(string ID)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'";

            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {


                    try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = sql;
                        conn.Open();
                        SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            scannedUser.ID = reader.GetString(1);
                            scannedUser.Password = reader.GetString(2);
                            scannedUser.PPicture = Cryptorizer.Base64ToImage(reader.GetString(3));
                            scannedUser.FName = reader.GetString(4);
                            scannedUser.MName = reader.GetString(5);
                            scannedUser.LName = reader.GetString(6);
                            scannedUser.Agency = reader.GetString(7);
                            scannedUser.Position = reader.GetString(8);
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your problem, but there is no reason to not do it right:

```cs
public static void AddAttendance(string id, string datetime, string action, string session)
{
    try
    {
        using (var sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = " + database + "; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;")
        {
            sqlite_conn.Open();
            using (var sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand())
            { 
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AttendanceLog (UserID, DateTime, Action, Session) VALUES (@Id, @DateTime, @Action, @Session);";
                sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = id;
                sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DateTime", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = datetime;
                sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Action", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = action;
                sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Session", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = session;
                sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This way your connection and SqlCommand are closed and disposed of and you are using a parameterized query, that will prevent SQL Injection. If your database column is not NVarChar, you need to change that. You can also add a length to your parameter definitions.

Comment: this doesnt work. Also i already did the parameterized thingy.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: It still throws me database is locked

Comment: OK, so it doesn't solve your problem. But it still works. As I understand it Kiosk mode runs under other credentials. Have you considered that the normal user might not have the necessary permissions for where the database is stored?

Comment: hold on. lemme record a video of it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mJ3o3ykQrw 

Here

Comment: It looks like you have plenty of other access to the database. It's a little blurry, but 6 seconds into the video it looks like there's a database reader that's never closed or disposed of. The using pattern really helps in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

This locking problem arises from trying to re-use the database connection. ADO.Net has a feature called connection pooling, such that re-using the same conenction object throughout your app is a *really bad idea* that will actually make things *slower*, in addition to leading to locking issues like this.

Instead, you really should create a brand new connection object for most queries, open the connection immediately before running the query, and **dispose** the object as soon as the query is finished. The easiest way to accomplish this is via a `using` block:

```
private static string ConnectionString {get;} = "Data Source = " + database + "; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;"

public static void AddAttendance(string ID, string dateTime, string Action, string Session)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO AttendanceLog (UserID, DateTime, Action, Session) VALUES (@id, @time, @action, @session);";

    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
        // Note the DateTime format. It's necessary to store date values in this way in order to preserve cardinality and allow indexes and date math to function properly.
        // Better DB platforms would have a DateTime type to use instead
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", DateTime.Parse(dateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", Action);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@session", session);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The `using` block will **guarantee** the connection is closed properly, even in cases where the `sqllite_conn.Close()` call might have been missed.

---

Here's the thing: **fixing this one query is not enough!**

*You must fix **ALL** of your queries to rely on the `using` block,* or you're still at risk for locking. The locking problem will not show on the query that is actually causing the lock, but the query you run **after** the database was locked.

In this case, it looks like the locking problem might happen at the point where you show the grid. The grid query runs fun, and doesn't show any errors, but doesn't release its locks, and so you get the error trying to add the records because is the next query after that.

The same is true for parameters. It's *not enough* for just this query to use query parameters instead of string concatenation. You must do this ***EVERY TIME*** you substitute data into an SQL string, in ***EVERY QUERY***.

Comment: I changed all my connections to that approach and is still giving me database is locked

Comment: i even used the using on the grid beforehand. Still giving me locking. Tried redoing it still does the same. I can send another video if you wanna see for yourself.

Comment: Here's my DatabaseHandles code https://pastebin.com/w7VxF9sj

Comment: Here's the function that loads the table https://pastebin.com/y1edfjAf

Comment: Honestly, if it is to lock because something isnt closed properly, then the same thing at Kiosk mode wouldnt go through as well, assuming you watched the video, it went through just fine.

And as expected, after I rewritten everything to 'using' approach, it does the same thing. I mean, it really is visible on its behavior. So something else mightve been locking it. Gosh this is why i love programming

Comment: Stop with the videos. That's not how Stack Overflow works.