# What is the best way to retrieve data each second from sqlite table (at the same time inserting the rows to the same table in other thread)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using sqlite database to store tick data in a table, at the same time I have a requirement to fetch the data each second from the table.

I have written following sample code in python to test this.

```
def get_ltp():
    query = """select * from test order by rowid desc LIMIT 1"""
    results = c.execute(query).fetchall()
    for i in results:
        print(i)

import time
for i in range(20):
    get_ltp()
    time.sleep(1)
```

when I'm executing this after fetching the data for few seconds, I'm getting "**database is locked**" error. Can anyone please help me on what is going wrong here? Inserting the data and retrieving the data at the same time - does sqlite is the right choice for this requirement?

Comment: A quick search would have helped you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10387821/4151233

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was pretty old post and not applicable now. But, I'll try it out. Thanks for your time.